# Cannot use custom key words with pvporcupine

Tags: python-3.x, ioerror

I have already created an account in picovoice and recieved an access key, but when I try to put the path of my ppn file, it shows an error:
`

```
[ERROR] loading keyword file at 'C:\Users\Priyam\Desktop\hey keyazip' failed with 'IO_ERROR'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Personal Project\import struct.py", line 13, in <module>
    porcupine = pvporcupine.create(access_key='access key',
  File "C:\Users\Priyam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pvporcupine\__init__.py", line 77, in create       
    return Porcupine(
  File "C:\Users\Priyam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pvporcupine\porcupine.py", line 158, in __init__   
    raise self._PICOVOICE_STATUS_TO_EXCEPTION[status]()
pvporcupine.porcupine.PorcupineIOError
```

the code is:
`

```
porcupine=None
paud=None
audio_stream=None

try:
    access_key="access key" 
    porcupine = pvporcupine.create(access_key='access key',
    keyword_paths=['C:\\Users\Priyam\Desktop\hey keyazip'],keywords=['hey keya']) #pvporcupine.KEYWORDS for all keywords
    paud=pyaudio.PyAudio()
    audio_stream=paud.open(rate=porcupine.sample_rate,channels=1,format=pyaudio.paInt16,input=True,frames_per_buffer=porcupine.frame_length)
    while True:
        keyword=audio_stream.read(porcupine.frame_length)
        keyword=struct.unpack_from("h"*porcupine.frame_length,keyword)
        keyword_index=porcupine.process(keyword)
        if keyword_index>=0:
            print("hotword detected")
            

finally:
    if porcupine is not None:
        porcupine.delete()
    if audio_stream is not None:
        audio_stream.close()
    if paud is not None:
        paud.terminate()
```

`

I tried the code above and the code provided by picovoice itself, yet I am facing the same issues

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Porcupine is having trouble finding your keyword file: `[ERROR] loading keyword file at 'C:\Users\Priyam\Desktop\hey keyazip' failed with 'IO_ERROR'`.

The Picovoice console provides the keyword inside a compressed `.zip` file. You will need to decompress the file and in your code update the path to lead to the `.ppn` file located inside. For example: `C:\\Users\Priyam\Desktop\hey-keya_en_windows_v2_1_0\hey-keya_en_windows_v2_1_0.ppn`